# Endless loop IntNode

Tags: c#

before showing the issue, look at the IntNode class:

```
class IntNode
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public IntNode next { get; set; }

    public IntNode(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public IntNode(int value, IntNode next)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public bool HasNext ()
    {
        return (this.next != null);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (this.HasNext())
            return this.value + " --> " + this.next;
        else
            return this.value + ". [end]";
    }
}
```

I have the following function:

```
static IntNode Sort (IntNode head)
{
    IntNode pos = head.next;
    IntNode current = head;
    IntNode prev = head;
    bool changed = false;

    while (current != null)
    {
        while (pos != null)
        {
            if (current.value > pos.value)
            {
                if (pos.HasNext()) current.next = pos.next;
                else prev.next = pos;
                pos.next = current;
                changed = true;
                if (current.next.HasNext())
                    pos = current.next.next;
                break;
            }

            pos = pos.next;
        }
        if (!changed)
        {
            current.next = head;
            head = current;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current.next;
        changed = false;
    }
    return head;
}
```

But when I am launching the program (with given parameters) it is not responding (a "-" appears and disappears) I dont know why it is like that and I am sitting on this a hour...

The purpose of the program is to a list and sort it from smaller to bigger and than return the edited list (dont create another list).

For Example:

**Given list:**

> 6,-4,5,0

**Output:**

> -4,0,5,6

Thanks!

Comment: That's a good chance to start using a debugger.

Comment: @zerkms what is a debugger and how I should use it?

Comment: It depends on what IDE/Editor you have. Google by "<your ide name> debugger"

Comment: Edit your question

Comment: @zerkms I am programming with Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: So, now you know how to search for further details.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar what should I fix?

Comment: @zerkms I didnt understand you... :\

Comment: Then read my 2nd comment once again.

Comment: Press F11 the program will run. you see yellow highlighted on first line press F11 again to step forward. hold mouse on variables to see details. you will figure it out. (if you want to go through methods and calls press F11 otherwise press F10. ) you can also put breakpoints to only stop at specific line you can learn these easily on internet.

Comment: Use a web search to find a tutorial about debugging C# code.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary wow thanks man! powerful tool!

Comment: In addition to the suggestions for how to use the debugger (yes, it's a powerful, even _critically useful_, tool for programmers), I will also suggest that you get in the habit of "encapsulating". For example, rather than mix code that handles moving a list element from one place to another with code that is supposed to logically analyze order and sort the list, break those pieces of code into separate methods and test each individually. In that way, you can verify and debug smaller pieces of code at a time, making the task a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I can see several issues with how your bubble sort is written.  If you don't have a debugger it will be difficult to debug manually.  Here is an insertion sort that may do the trick for you and be easier to trace mentally.  It finds the lowest value and moves it to a different list.

```
static IntNode Sort (IntNode head)
{
    IntNode resultTail = null;
    IntNode resultHead = null;
    IntNode current = head;
    IntNode lowestPrev = null;
    IntNode lowest = head;

    while (head != null)
    {
        lowestPrev = null;
        current = head;

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.value < lowest.value)
            {
                lowest = current;
                lowestPrev = prev;
            }

            prev = current
            current = current.next;
        }

        if (resultHead = null)
        {
            resultHead = lowest;
            resultTail = lowest;
        }
        else
            resultTail.next = lowest;

        if (lowest == head)
          head = head.next;
        else
            lowestPrev.next = lowest.next;

    }

    return resultHead;    
}
```

Comment: Tahnks, but I shouldnt create a new list (the resultHead and resultTrail). I should edit the existed list... I have found too many problems in my program with the debugger so I will be happy if you can write a new function for me that sorts the given list without creating a new one